# update html according to json

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have a JSON script which contain live matches. These changes every 5 minutes. The changes could for instance be the keys live_in or score. Beside this matches are also deleted and added to the JSON. I want to keep my html output updated at all time how can i do this the best possible way? So far i've set the updating speed to 5 seconds for testing purposes. I've tried so far to set the divs id to equal to the match_id and thereby update by

```
    $('div#match-date-id-' + match['match_id']).html('test');
```

However does not seem to update. How can i do this the best possible way? i've created a plnkr which enable you to download it with a json snippet, which can be edited in order to check.

plnkr.co/edit/eQCShhW01OG5jU4VLx04?p=preview

Comment: Reading from your code I'm a bit lost. Can you compact your code so that it is the most minimal amount of code but still contains the problem

Comment: I had a glance and it looks your ids are in general like this: <div class="result-date" id="match-date-id-1m 36s"></div> and so  on. In your json data "match_id": "65551" are numbers, so I don't think there is a match when using your jQuery selector above. So it's hard to make updates.

Comment: Okay yes clearly a mistake from my side i've updated now. However it does not seem to update the live in now even though i change the live in key in the JSON http://plnkr.co/edit/eQCShhW01OG5jU4VLx04?p=preview

Comment: Your ajax code is definitely running. 

It's your selectors that I believe is the issue. First off most of your html ids are written wrong. Your id's are like this: "match-date-id-1m 36s". You cannot contain spaces in ids. 

Also in your selectors you are trying to detect things like this: "#match-date-id-67843", but there is nothing in your HTML that matches.

Comment: In your your  function matchHtml(obj, type) you are creating divs with the following code: html += '<div class="result-date"  id="match-date-id-' + obj['live in'] + '">';  should you use obj['match_id'] instead of obj['live in'] ?

Comment: hi yahya i added a old script by mistake check the new one. check above comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad earlier on :-) Now I've done more thorough testing and **updated** the [plunker code](http://plnkr.co/edit/5DXZgUD838EVAMLISmJC?p=preview). What I found in the test: the `filter` was trying to use an *undefined* value (`match.id`), also the filter was trying to compare values from different datatypes (*String* vs. *Integer*); so it wasn't working as intended:

Original:

```
   match = match.filter(
      function(match) {
        return match.id > lastId;
   });
```

Corrected code:

```
    match = match.filter(
        function(match) {
          return parseInt(match.match_id) > lastId;
     });
```

Above `match_id` represents String datatype in your JSON file, so I had to convert it to *Integer* before comparison. More info about JSON [data-types](https://www.json.com/#data-types). Following the older `filter` functionality, no match passed the comparison test.

Also for testing purposes I commented out the following line:

```
        if (match.match_id > lastLoadedMatch) {
           //lastLoadedMatch = match.match_id
        }
```

because in the second round of updates with the same testing data, no data passes that condition.

Also, I think you need to convert `match_id` to *Integer* as well; like following:

```
        var matchId = parseInt(match.match_id)
        if ( matchId > lastLoadedMatch) {
           lastLoadedMatch = match.match_id
        }
```

I hope you find it useful :-) + note I added a timestamp for those updates; so it's clearly visible that the updates take place now every 5 seconds.

Comment: Okay could u send a plnkr on the exact script u use for it to work? since it still does not work in mine?

Comment: @PeterPik Here is http://plnkr.co/edit/5DXZgUD838EVAMLISmJC?p=preview   where the first 4 of JSON data 'live in' keys have been changed to 'live_in'

Comment: plnkr updates everytime u do changes to the JSON or other things, so sure it is not just therefor it is working? since it is not working on my server? not updating

Comment: @PeterPik hmm.. it's the first time I'm editing plunker code sample so there could be hick-ups I guess, but I tried to edit your original code sample by replacing the space  in ....html(match['live in']); with underscore _ and and in the json data respectively, I was able to get updates. In any case, I need to call it a day. Good luck!

Comment: @PeterPik updated the answer. It looks like it was a filter issue.